# stack smashing detected because of strncpy

Tags: c, string, text, tokenize, strncpy

I have a problem in a c program. I made a function which tokenizes variables from a textfile and saves them inot a set. The problem is that the strncpy function from string.h behaves strange in my program. I broke my code down to minimal example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void tokenizeWord(int *i, char *text);

int main() {
    char *text = "hallo 123 test foo bar etc";
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
        switch(text[i]){
            case ' ':
                i++;
            default:
                tokenizeWord(&i, text);

        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void tokenizeWord(int *i, char *text) {
    bool eow = false;
    int start = *i;
    int end = start;
    if (i != NULL) {
        while (*i < strlen(text) && !eow)  {
            switch(text[*i]) {
                case ' ':
                    end = (*i);
                    eow = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    (*i)++;
                    break;
            }
        }
        char out[8] = "";
        strncpy(out, text+start, end);
        out[end-start] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", out);
    }
}
```

The first variable which is printed out is "hallo", what is totally correct behaviour. The secound variable already contains "123 test". But because I set the \0 after 123 the rest won't get printed. Immediately after the print, I get a *** stack smashing detected *** abort. I think the problem is, that the strncpy function tries to write more than 8 characters, but i told the function to print from text at position 6 to 9. So why strncpy tries to copy more than three characters?

I don't have much experience in C programming and tried many things, like debugging and printouts to find the problem, but I have no clue yet. I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: `end` increments just as start does.  Try to pass `end-start` as the length of the string to `strncpy`.  To debug, add a `printf("start=%d end=%d\n", start, end)` right after the while loop.

Comment: Thank you very much. But the problem was't that end = start, but the third argument of strncpy wanted the distance to iterate and not the end point. After reading the doc i thought that the third argument is the end position. Here is the output of the print:start=0 end=5
hallo
start=6 end=9
123
start=10 end=14
test
start=15 end=18
foo
start=19 end=22
bar
start=23 end=23

Comment: The third argument to [strncpy](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy) is the number of bytes you want to copy, not the end position.  The number of bytes is the difference `end-start`.  From your output it looks like both `start` and `end` increment correctly.  The stack smash comes from writing beyond the 8 bytes of the `out` character array.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following

```
strncpy(out, text+start, end);
```

To

```
strncpy(out, text+start, end-start);
```

if start = 6 and end = 9 then you are copying 9 bytes and not 3.

Read More about [Stack Smashing](http://poeticcoding.com/main/c-programing/ccpp-stack-smashing/).